# da Vinci Jr. nozzle diagram

Tags: maintenance, nozzle

Has anybody taken apart a da Vinci Jr. 3D printer nozzle?

My first time trying to clean the nozzle after it jammed, I broke off the filament immediately before it gets heated, inside the nozzle assembly. The XYZprinting video, ["da Vinci Jr. 1.0 - Advanced Nozzle Cleaning"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIuyXQroetU), shows the filament coming out easily when heated, but now I'm seeing that I should have cut the filament by the feeder and pulled it out after heating.

I have a long length of wire that is similar to the tiny cleaning wire that comes with the kit. Is it safe to heat up the nozzle and push the wire all the way through?

I tried pushing from the other direction with the large cleaning tool (as shown in [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZIuyXQroetU)). I also tried heating the tip of the filament and pushing it to the jammed filament inside the nozzle and reconnecting it. It held a while as I tried wiggling it when heated but did not break the jam loose and broke off again...

What should I do?

Comment: If the wire is the same diameter as teh cleaning wire (or less), then OK to use.  There's a number of kits out there which provide what are essentially  ultra-small diameter drill bits for cleaning nozzles.   For that matter, replacement nozzles are pretty cheap, tho' I'm not knowledgeable about compatibility with daVincis

Comment: OK well I tried with a drill bit, not long enough so I unscrewed the small gromet bushing that holds in the feeder tube one the top of the black nozzle assembly box ( it sticks up about a quarter inch, it looks like stainless steel and has a black rubber washer gromet connected to the top to connect feeder tube.) Then, after trying again (no luck) I noticed the female threads that were inside the assembly were now gone... The top connector piece was screwed onto a small nut and now it is trapped inside the black box....

Comment: Now can how can I take the dang thing apart or do I even need extra small torq bits???     please don't reply unless you have dealt with this machine before I'm trying to fix the one I have if possible and not break it

Comment: Have you managed to resolve your issue yet? If so, could you post the solution in an answer? I think that a tried, and tested, solution would be rather useful for other users. Have you tried emailing XYZprinting tech support for a solution?

Answer (score 2):

After watching the video, it looks this is a Bowden style extruder.  The extruder assembly is encased in the black box the OP mentions.  The assembly is user removable.  It appears they also include two cleaning tools

- Small (0.4mm?) wire to clean the nozzle tip
- Large (1.7mm?) rod for pushing filament down that is stuck in the cold end

It appears the OP tried accessing the filament in the cold end by removing the fitting at the top of the assembly without opening the assembly.  Unfortunately that caused the nut holding the fitting on from the inside fell off.  At that point he was in a bit of a mess.

I believe the manufacture's intent is to "ram" any broken pieces in the cold end through the hot extruder by using the provided rod and pushing while the extruder is on.  It seems that it should work but would not be easy to do if the filament broke off outside the extruder (which seems to be the case).

At the point he left it, it would seem that he would either have to do surgery or replace the extruder assembly.